# Simple string repeater program

Tags: beginner, c, strings

I'm new to C, want to know if I'm doing this right.

```
//repstring.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Initialize variables and pointers
     int i;
     int loop;
     char *deststr;
     char *str;

     //Change second argument to integer
     loop = atoi(argv[2]);

    //If user requests to repeat string more than 9999 times, terminate
    if(loop > 9999)
    {
        printf("Error: Asked to repeat too many times.\n");
        printf("Hardcoded maximum: 9999\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(argc == 3)
    {

        //Dynamically allocate memory to strings
        deststr = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024  * sizeof(char));
        str = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024  * sizeof(char));

        if(str == NULL || deststr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
            free(deststr);
            free(str);
            return 1;
        }

        //Copy string in first argument to str
        strncpy(str, argv[1], 50);

        //Append str to deststr for amount of times specified in second argument
        for(i = 0; i < loop ; i++)
        {
            strcat(deststr, str);
        }

        //Print repeated string to stdout
        printf("%s\n", deststr);

        //Free allocated memory
        free(deststr);
        free(str);


    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: repstring <string> <amount of times to repeat>\n");
        return 1;
    }


 return 0;
}
```

Is there anything that could be otherwise improved? Am I handling memory correctly?
Review would be very appreciated.

Comment: What's your primary goal — to get repeated output printed, or to play around with memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Standard guarantees `sizeof(char)` to be 1.
- `argv[1]` is a perfectly good string. There is no need to copy it anywhere, let alone allocate a megabyte for it.
- Length of a destination string is `strlen(argv[1]) * loop + 1`. Do not hardcode a megabyte.
- `strcat` has to find the end of destination string over and over again, making the execution time quadratic. Trace the end of the destination string as you go and `strcpy` to the right location instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much to offer other than I see some magic numbers in there. For example:

```
if(loop > 9999)
```

and

```
strncpy(str, argv[1], 50);
```

Good example is the `9999`. Make that into a variable then you can change either statically or dynamically and you would only have to make the change in one place.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the  repeated strings, you do not need to allocate memory, a simple loop can suffice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    puts(argv[2]);
}
```